# How to get inbuilt settings information in label in iphone?

Tags: iphone

In my application I want to retrieve the information of user iPhone device about the settings relating to Alaram/Bell etc and add all those information in my label which I have created prior.

So that we can proceed in my program further.

please help me out its urget.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through the `UIDevice.h` header file in the UIKit framework for a list of properties, or read the excellent [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-DontLinkElementID_5).